# Operand error in case constructing

Tags: mysql, sql, case

```
SElECT CASE 
WHEN TIME(`last_log_in`) < DATE_ADD(`last_log_in`, INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
THEN
(
SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `id`=1
)
ELSE
false
END
FROM `accounts`
```

What's wrong? i got "#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)".

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: make it simple `select * from accounts where TIME(last_log_in) < DATE_ADD(last_log_in, INTERVAL 1 DAY) `, what you are trying with case statement is not a correct way